# Logging retries with Reactor Mono

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using Reactive Streams to call a web service, and have configured an automatic retry policy so that if the initial call fails a number of retries will be attempted. I would like to be able to log each of the retries, but can't find a way to do this in [the documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html). The Mono object has `doOn...` methods for various events such as success, failure etc but I can't see `doOnRetry`. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? My code looks something like this:

```
return webClient.get()
    .uri(myUrl)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
    .retryBackoff(RETRIES, MIN_BACKOFF_DURATION, MAX_BACKOFF_DURATION)
    .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> LOGGER.info("subscribe"))
    .doOnSuccess(result -> LOGGER.info("success"))
    //.doOnRetry(something -> LOGGER.info("retry")) <-- I want to do this
    .doOnError(err -> LOGGER.info("error"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do this by adding the [Reactor Extra Utilities](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-extra) package to my project. This allowed me to replace the `retryBackoff` method in the above example with the following:

```
.retryWhen(Retry.any()
    .retryMax(RETRIES)
    .exponentialBackoff(MIN_BACKOFF_DURATION, MAX_BACKOFF_DURATION)
    .doOnRetry(context -> LOGGER.warn("retry")))
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting with [Reactor Core, Version 3.3.4](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/releases/tag/v3.3.4.RELEASE) you may use the overhauled `retryWhen` model; like:

```
[...]
.retryWhen(Retry.backoff(5, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> {
            log.error("Retrying: "
                    + retrySignal.totalRetries() + "; "
                    + retrySignal.totalRetriesInARow() + "; "
                    + retrySignal.failure());
        }));
```

Comment: Yes think this makes more sense than the util unless working on an old version  of reactor